# iOS one signal "AppDelegate.swift:13:8: No such module 'OneSignal'"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode8, onesignal

[image][image]I installed one signal module through cocapods for Xcode8 and I'm not able to import the module into my code . Im seeing the following error "AppDelegate.swift:13:8: No such module 'OneSignal". I used "use_frameworks" in the pod file and I also set my "Framework Search Paths" in the Build settings to point to the dir . I cleaned the project, deleted Derived Data folder but still no luck . I'm attaching a few screen shots that could better explain the problem . I've been stuck on this for quite a while now and any help is very much appriciated [image]

Comment: let me see your Podfile

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I attached the a screenshot of the PodFile at the top of the post

Comment: Have you tried to install the pods anew? Delete the pod file, pod init, pod install, then copy paste the old file, pod install, pod update?

Comment: I tried to create a demo with Podfile `platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'DemoOneSignal' do
pod 'OneSignal'
end` and it was okay, no problem! Try to uncomment this line `platform :ios, '9.0'`

Comment: That is wonderful It worked like a charm , Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: Is my answer useful? Please upvote me. Thank you!

Comment: Actually It indexed successfully but I'm still getting the same error , I was so excited to see a success message and jumped the gun . I still get the same error :(

Comment: I alos deleted the pod file created a new one and copied my code into the new podfile and ran pod install. It's the same error

Comment: I created a new project and added the pod file with just OneSignal . I get the same error . here is my new test pod file `# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  use_frameworks!
target 'OnesignalDemo' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  # Pods for OnesignalDemo

  target 'OnesignalDemoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'OnesignalDemoUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
   pod 'OneSignal'
end`